# Visualize the distribution of classes in each mini-batch of a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, descriptive-statistics

I want to observe the distribution of classes in each mini-batch of a dataset to see how the `WeightedRandomSampler` works in PyTorch.

How would I go about doing that?

Let's say my mini-batch size is 8 and number of classes is also 8.

e.g. of a mini-batch - `[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]`. I have 863 such mini-batches. There are 8 classes are - `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`.

I iterated through each all mini-batches and stored the count of each class into 8 separate lists. For e.g. `class_1 = [3, 4, 3, 3, 5, ....]`. There are 863 numbers in each list (because we have 863 mini-batches as mentioned above).

How would I now verify that indeed all the classes in each batch are balanced. That is, all classes have a balanced representation in each batch (based on their frequency in the whole dataset).

Now, I initially thought I could construct a line-plot of each class where x-axis contains the mini-batch number and the y-axis contains the number of samples of each class per batch. So, if all 8 classes follow the same pattern (rise and fall), then I'll know that each batch contains the classes in a weighted manner ie. the overall distribution of classes is represented in each batch. Is this true?

But this method does not seem robust enough considering a large number of samples.

Then I plotted the density curves of each classes in all of the mini-batches. In the following image, I have plotted the `distplot()` for 4 classes (red, blue, green, and orange). To plot these density curves, I took the number of samples of a class in batch and called `distplot()` on it.

[image]

In this graph, I observe that rise and fall of each plot lies on the same place in x-axis. Does this mean that there is a weighted distribution of the classes in my mini-batches? If not, then how do I verify/analyse the distribution of classes in a batch?

Comment: "In this graph, I observe that rise and fall of each plot lies on the same place in x-axis." 

How many samples do you have with class label `0.5` or `1.5` or `2.5`?

Comment: The labels are all integers. This is an image classification task where I converted the labels from strings to integers. So, the classes are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

Comment: So why are you surprised that there is a rising and falling pattern? There are 0 observations with values between the integers, so the plot seems consistent with these expectations.

Comment: I'm not surprised by the rising and falling pattern. All 4 classes (red, blue, green, and orange) rise and fall in the same place on the x-axis in the density plot I constructed. What I've plotted is - I put the number of samples per class from each batch into 8 separate lists and made a density plot out of it. Does this density plot tell me about the distribution of classes in the batches?

Comment: I've edited the question with a little more explanation. Please see if it clarifies my question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional elaboration. It sounds like you're asking how to test whether the mini-batches are, indeed, realizations from a multivariate hypergeometric distribution. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: I have no idea what `multivariate hypergeometric distribution` is. But essentially yeah. I want to test if the number of samples in each mini-batch, across all classes, are in proportion. Let's say if I had 100 samples consisting of classes `1, 2, 3` where there are 50 samples of `1`, 30 samples of `2`, and 20 samples of `3`. Then the weight of these samples are 1/50, 1/30, and 1/20 ie.giving more weight to underrepresented class. Now, when I make mini-batches out of these, I would expect that the ratio of number of samples of these three classes would be maintained (1/50:1/30:1/20).

Comment: Even if we don't consider all the weighting of classes and everything. Assume, I randomly choose samples for my mini-batch, is there a way to check how they're distributed in each mini-batch? Kind of arrive at a summary statistic or visualization? Like, I would not want a mini-batch to contain all samples from class-1 for instance.

Comment: You could use an internet search, or a search of this website, to learn more about unfamiliar statistical terms. The nature of randomness is that it's impossible to guarantee an outcome, except under unusual circumstances. There's a (small) probability that you can flip a fair coin 10 times and always turn up heads. Likewise, random sampling without replacement when the mini-batch size is "small" will never be guaranteed to always produce a balanced batch size.

Comment: cross-posted to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61136963/visualize-the-distribution-of-classes-in-each-mini-batch-of-a-dataset